# Space between top of website and button?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

After downloading a CSS button from the internet, it looks really good. However, It's way too down on the website (run code snippet for more info) sorry for the messy CSS, and HTML. (JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mffeswxs)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>QuickAdvertize - Your source for quickly advertising and finding new businesses.</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <div class="flex">
            <a href="index.html" class="bttn">Home</a>
            <a href="advertise.html" class="bttn">Advertise</a>
            <a href="guides.html" class="bttn">Find</a>
        </div>
        <h1 style="text-align:center;">
            QuickAdvertize.com<br>
            <small>Your source for reliable businesses.</small>
        </h1>
        <hr width="30%">
        <br>
        <p>
            QuickAdvertize.com gives you the tools & resources to allow you to either find<br>
            or manage your business online.
        </p>
        <p id="businessamount"></p>
        <br>
        <hr width="30%">
        <h1>FAQ</h1>
        <h2>What is QuickAdvertize?</h2>
        <p>
            QuickAdvertize is a social platform that allows you to find<br>
            and upload businesses online with just a few clicks.
        </p>
        <h2>How do you find a business?</h2>
        <p>
            It's simple! Just click on Find. You can search for a business<br>
            or find businesses just by looking!
        </p>
        <h2>What is a premium business?</h2>
        <p>
            Premium businesses are companies that are developed and<br> 
            sometimes can provide better care and support with products.
        </p>
        <h2>Is a purchase required to find a business?</h2>
        <p>
            No! It's completely free, without the hassle of creating an<br>
            account.
        </p>
        <h2>Is a purchase required to upload a business?</h2>
        <p>
            Yes. However, there are multiple plans that you can pick.<br>
            <b>Guest</b> plans will take about 12-24 hours to be delivered.<br>
            <b>Popular</b> plans will take about 12-36 hours to be delivered.<br>
            <b>Expert</b> plans will take about 12-48 hours to be delivered.<br>
            Note: If the plans take more than a week to deliver, that means<br>
            there is something wrong. Please e-mail using the chat system.</p>
            <p><a href="termsofuse.html" style="font-size: 80%;">Terms Of Use</a></p>
        </center>
        <script type='text/javascript' data-cfasync='false'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: here is the snippet link: https://jsfiddle.net/mffeswxs/

Comment: what button? I don't see a button.

Comment: and update your post with the code from your fiddle please. No need for jsfiddle, you can include the code here on stack overflow.

Comment: What do you mean? It's on the top of the page and says HOME
ADVERTISE
FIND

Comment: @MichaelCoker sorry very unknowledgeable about how stackoverflow.com works

Comment: It's ok, here's a learning opportunity. Edit your post and include the code in the post. And remove `min-height: 50vh;` from `.flex`

Comment: @MichealCoker Thanks! IT worked :)

Comment: @MichealCoker No wonder you're in the top 0.01% :) im gonna give you a rep

Comment: @htmlJohn by the way, you have html errors, you have a </p> and a </a> which should be reversed and <head> should be before <body>, take a look at the edit I made to your post

Comment: no problem :) and thanks!

Comment: Be sure to check your code out with an [html validator](https://validator.w3.org/) and a [css validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) They're helpful at identifying unclosed tags and pointing out deprecated and unsupported tags like `<center>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove min-height from `.flex` in your **CSS**:

```
.flex {
    min-height: 0;
}
```

Comment: in 4mins because I have to wait

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't see the 'Show 5 more comments' tag. I'm sorry. Hope it will help other people then.

Comment: There is no reason to use `min-height: none;` (which by the way should be `auto`, not `none`), simply remove the `min-height: 50vh;` from the rule

Comment: True, but I always try to leave the original library untouched and overwrite it in my main style sheet. The default value of min-height is 0.